# TCPDF error on PHP Version 7

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm using http://tcpdf.org plugin to generate PDF417 bar code in PHP.

But this plugin has an error in PHP 7. (In PHP 5.6 without error and works normal)

Here is the error:
[image]

And my code is:

```php
require "tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php";
$barcodeObject=new TCPDF2DBarcode("12364524"),"PDF417");
$image=$barcodeObject->getBarcodePNG(10,5);
```

Comment: Look for the info on negative bit shifts on this page. http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Comment: Thanks. I fixed this problem with your help. I will send answer as soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this error, we can edit this file: tcpdf/include/barcodes/pdf417.php (Line 747)

Old code:

```
$errsize = (2 << $ecl);
if ($maxerrsize >= $errsize)
{
    break;
}
```

New code:

```
if($ecl>=0)
{
    $errsize = (2 << $ecl);
    if ($maxerrsize >= $errsize)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```